# Count the number of unique dates per ID between 2 dates, conditionally

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have a main table that contains the dates of main events for each personid:

```
dfMain <- data.frame(last    = c("2017-08-01", "2017-08-01", "2017-08-05","2017-09-02","2017-09-02"),
                 previous    = c(NA, NA, "2017-08-01", "2017-08-05", "2017-08-01"),
                 personid    = c(12341, 122345, 12341, 12341, 122345),
                 diff        = c(NA, NA, 4, 28, 32))
```

(The NAs on the "previous" and "diff" variables indicate that this personid had his first "main even" i.e: no previous dates and no time difference)

I also have a secondary table that consists of a "secondary event" for each personid:

```
dfSecondary <- data.frame(date = c("2017-09-01", "2017-08-30", "2017-08-04", "2017-08-02", "2017-08-02"),
                      personid = c(122345, 122345, 12341, 122345, 12341))
```

My question is, What is the **optimal way** (due to the volume of my data) to augment my "dfMain" data frame with the number of unique secondary events between main event dates for each personid.

In the dummy example my objective is to get this table:

```
Occurances  <- c(NA, NA, 2, 0, 3)
dfObjective <- data.frame(dfMain, Occurances)
```

Comment: When you are asking questions that involve dates, it is useful to `dput` your example so that it includes the date variables as Date objects. It is a pain for us to perform this conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm new to the community so apologies for any inconvenience caused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Jaap's `data.table` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46038993/3817004) using a *non-equi join* can be condensed in a "one-liner":

```
dfMain[, Occurrences := dfSecondary[dfMain, 
                                    on = .(personid, date <= last, date >= previous), 
                                    .N, by = .EACHI]$N][]
```

> ```
>          last   previous personid diff Occurrences
> 1: 2017-08-01       <NA>    12341   NA           0
> 2: 2017-08-01       <NA>   122345   NA           0
> 3: 2017-08-05 2017-08-01    12341    4           2
> 4: 2017-09-02 2017-08-05    12341   28           0
> 5: 2017-09-02 2017-08-01   122345   32           3
> ```

`dfSecondary[dfMain, ...]` is a *non-equi* right join which takes all rows of `dfMain` and aggregates in the join. The result has the same number and ordering of rows as `dfMain`. So, we can pick the count column `N` and create the new `Occurrences` column.

*Non-equi* joins is a new feature introduced to `data.table` with version 1.9.8 (on CRAN 25 Nov 2016).

#### Data

The sample data sets need to be coerced to class `data.table` and the various date columns need to be converted to a date class.

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("last", "previous")
setDT(dfMain)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.IDate), .SDcols = cols][]
setDT(dfSecondary)[, date := as.IDate(date)][]
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the `data.table`-package:

```
# load 'data.table' package and convert date-columns to date-class
library(data.table)
setDT(dfMain)[, 1:2 := lapply(.SD, as.IDate), .SDcols = 1:2][]
setDT(dfSecondary)[, date := as.IDate(date)][]

# create a reference
dfSecondary <- dfSecondary[dfMain
                           , on = .(personid, date > previous, date < last)
                           , .(dates = x.date)
                           , by = .EACHI]
setnames(dfSecondary, 2:3, c('previous','last'))

# join and summarise
dfMain[na.omit(dfSecondary, cols = 1:3)[, sum(!is.na(dates), na.rm = TRUE)
                                        , by = .(personid, previous, last)]
       , on = .(personid, previous, last)
       , Occ := V1][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>          last   previous personid diff Occ
> 1: 2017-08-01       <NA>    12341   NA  NA
> 2: 2017-08-01       <NA>   122345   NA  NA
> 3: 2017-08-05 2017-08-01    12341    4   2
> 4: 2017-09-02 2017-08-05    12341   28   0
> 5: 2017-09-02 2017-08-01   122345   32   3
> ```

Answer (score 3):

With `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dfMain %>%
  left_join(dfSecondary,by="personid") %>%                  # put everything together
  mutate_at(c("last","previous","date"),as.Date) %>%        # reformat as date
  mutate(is_between = date <= last & date >= previous) %>%  # tests if it's in between
  group_by(last,previous,personid,diff) %>%                 # group by columns from initial df
  summarize(Occ = sum(is_between)) %>%                      # count how many we have in between
  `[<-`(is.na(.$previous),"Occ",NA) %>%                     # add NAs where previous was NA
  ungroup                                                   # ungroup to have regular table

# # A tibble: 5 x 5
#         last   previous personid  diff   Occ
#       <date>     <date>    <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1 2017-08-01         NA    12341    NA    NA
# 2 2017-08-01         NA   122345    NA    NA
# 3 2017-08-05 2017-08-01    12341     4     2
# 4 2017-09-02 2017-08-01   122345    32     3
# 5 2017-09-02 2017-08-05    12341    28     0
```

Note: order has been altered, tell me if it's an issue and I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution from `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Convert columns of factor to date class
# Add an ID column
dfMain2 <- dfMain %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, as.Date) %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n())

# Convert columns of factor to date class
# Add a Count column
dfSecondary2 <- dfSecondary %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, as.Date) %>%
  mutate(Count = 1)

# Create sequence of dates between previous and last
# Unnest the data frame
# Perform join based on "Period" = "date", "personid"
# Group the data frame by ID and calculate the total count
dfMain3 <- dfMain2 %>%
  drop_na(previous) %>%
  mutate(Period = map2(previous, last, seq, by = 1)) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  left_join(dfSecondary2, by = c("Period" = "date", "personid")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Occurances = sum(Count, na.rm = TRUE))

# Join the data frame by ID to create dfObjective
dfObjective <- dfMain2 %>%
  left_join(dfMain3, by = "ID") %>%
  select(-ID)

dfObjective
        last   previous personid diff Occurances
1 2017-08-01       <NA>    12341   NA         NA
2 2017-08-01       <NA>   122345   NA         NA
3 2017-08-05 2017-08-01    12341    4          2
4 2017-09-02 2017-08-05    12341   28          0
5 2017-09-02 2017-08-01   122345   32          3
```

Data

```
dfMain <- data.frame(last    = c("2017-08-01", "2017-08-01", "2017-08-05","2017-09-02","2017-09-02"),
                     previous    = c(NA, NA, "2017-08-01", "2017-08-05", "2017-08-01"),
                     personid    = c(12341, 122345, 12341, 12341, 122345),
                     diff        = c(NA, NA, 4, 28, 32))


dfSecondary <- data.frame(date = c("2017-09-01", "2017-08-30", "2017-08-04", "2017-08-02", "2017-08-02"),
                          personid = c(122345, 122345, 12341, 122345, 12341))
```